# Spring Aop some maintenance

Tags: java, spring, architecture

I have a web application (Spring, Java) interacting with some "plugins" in my system (for example sending email, or saving user input when necessary) the communication is done with Spring AOP.

Because it is hard to maintain and debug now **I want to convert it to an Event-Based system, I want the same functionality to be done in java code events but not from Spring AOP.**

What do you think about this? Any inspiring ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for in JVM straight forward event system, it is worth looking at how Spring 's Apllication Events work. You can start from org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext. This class has code for publish events, register events etc. Spring also takes care of auto registration of listeners for a event.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [CDI Event](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_ee_6_observer_with) system and let you inspriate from that.

You can write your own  version of that for spring (maybe not with all the features, but with this nice handling approace).

Answer (score -1):

I think the first step you need to do is to get a book and have a basic understand about Observer pattern.  I will suggest you to take a look in Head First Design Pattern which is a great book for junior developer that is lacking of design experience.

After you have basic understanding about it, you may consider using Java's Observer/Observable, hand-crafting related interfaces, or using Spring's Application Event.  (But it is simply meaningless to ask people to teach you the whole pattern here, that's something you need to read before asking)

(And honestly, it is really really a bad idea to weave your logic using AOP like what you mentioned, it is not only hard to maintain but it is abusing AOP in a way that is not suitable)

Comment: well, I can't really understand why there is a down vote... it is so obvious that OP is not even doing enough for his work by studying the basics of observer pattern.  I did suggest what to study as a starter, and what's the subsequent steps he can take.  I really can't understand the reason for the down vote